# How to create .NET 5 application with Razor pages and Angular together?

Tags: angular, razor-pages, .net-5

I want to create a project that serves razor pages by default for all the routes. and route back to angular for specific routes.

I already done this using web api, and two UI projects, one for angular and one for Razor pages.

It works fine, but the deployment is a struggle each time. I want to use the default template from visual studio for Angular but keep the same behavior. Razor pages by default and Angular for specific paths.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible - but why?

Comment: @fredrik I already have the administration app built with Angular, I don't want to re-create everything from scratch. so I want to use the angular app for the admin routes only.

Comment: You're probably better of sticking with one or the other.

Comment: @IBRA can you show me how can you use two UI project ? I am trying to do the same. Angular for manageement application and Razor for report viewer purpose

Comment: @Sras I ended up using web api for back-end, razor pages in the same solution. and a separate angular project. the trick in deployment is to add the angular as a website, and add the web api project as an application. will try to provide an example in the weekend

Comment: @IBRA thank you . my email here: chhinsras@gmail.com